# Delete and Truncate and table size

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-delete, truncate

I tried this query to understand the impact on table size after delete and truncate.

```
select * from SALES_HISTORY;
Output:
Product     Month       Sales
sony    22-DEC-17   24000
sony    22-DEC-17   24000
sony    22-DEC-17   24000
sony    22-DEC-17   24000
sony    22-DEC-17   24000
sony    22-DEC-17   24000

Delete from sales_history:
commit;

select segment_name,segment_type,bytes/1024/1024 MB
from dba_segments
where segment_type='TABLE' and segment_name='SALES_HISTORY';

Output:
segment_name    segment_type   MB
SALES_HISTORY   TABLE         0.0625

Truncate table SALES_HISTORY;
```

After that, I again try finding size of table, but it seems the same as below. Shouldn't it should be zero if have truncated all of the rows?

```
Output:
segment_name    segment_type   MB
SALES_HISTORY   TABLE         0.0625
```

I need to understand the impact on the size of table and watermark after delete and truncate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few options for `truncate`, here's how these and `delete` affect the storage and high-water mark:

- `delete` leaves all the space allocated to the table. The high-water mark stays the same
- `truncate table ... reuse storage` leaves all the space allocated to the table. This resets the high-water mark to the first extent
- `truncate table ... drop storage` (the default) deallocates all the space above the `minextents` for the table. And consequently resets the high-water mark
- `truncate table ... drop all storage` deallocates all space from the table

You can verify this with `dbms_space.unused_space`:

```
create table t as 
  select level id, lpad ( 'x', 1000, 'x' ) stuff 
  from   dual
  connect by level <= 1000;

create or replace procedure show_size as

   out_total_blocks               integer;
   out_total_bytes                integer;
   out_unused_blocks              integer;
   out_unused_bytes               integer;
   out_last_used_extent_file_id   integer;
   out_last_used_extent_block_id  integer;
   out_last_used_block            integer;

begin

  dbms_space.unused_space(
    segment_owner              =>  user
    ,segment_name              =>  'T'
    ,segment_type              =>  'TABLE'
    ,total_blocks              =>  out_total_blocks
    ,total_bytes               =>  out_total_bytes 
    ,unused_blocks             =>  out_unused_blocks
    ,unused_bytes              =>  out_unused_bytes
    ,last_used_extent_file_id  =>  out_last_used_extent_file_id
    ,last_used_extent_block_id =>  out_last_used_extent_block_id
    ,last_used_block           =>  out_last_used_block
  );

  dbms_output.put_line ( 'Total Blocks:    ' ||  out_total_blocks || ' (blocks in the segment)');
  dbms_output.put_line ( 'Total Bytes:     ' ||  out_total_bytes || ' (segment size in bytes)');
  dbms_output.put_line ( 'Unused Blocks:   ' ||  out_unused_blocks || ' (empty blocks)');
  dbms_output.put_line ( 'Unused Bytes:    ' ||  out_unused_bytes || ' (size of empty space in bytes)');
  dbms_output.put_line ( 'Last Used Block: ' ||  out_last_used_block || ' (high water mark)');
end;
/ 

exec show_size;

Total Blocks:    256 (blocks in the segment)
Total Bytes:     2097152 (segment size in bytes)
Unused Blocks:   101 (empty blocks)
Unused Bytes:    827392 (size of empty space in bytes)
Last Used Block: 27 (high water mark)

delete t;
commit;

exec show_size;

Total Blocks:    256 (blocks in the segment)
Total Bytes:     2097152 (segment size in bytes)
Unused Blocks:   101 (empty blocks)
Unused Bytes:    827392 (size of empty space in bytes)
Last Used Block: 27 (high water mark)

truncate table t
  reuse storage;

exec show_size;

Total Blocks:    256 (blocks in the segment)
Total Bytes:     2097152 (segment size in bytes)
Unused Blocks:   253 (empty blocks)
Unused Bytes:    2072576 (size of empty space in bytes)
Last Used Block: 3 (high water mark)

truncate table t
  drop storage;

exec show_size;

Total Blocks:    8 (blocks in the segment)
Total Bytes:     65536 (segment size in bytes)
Unused Blocks:   5 (empty blocks)
Unused Bytes:    40960 (size of empty space in bytes)
Last Used Block: 3 (high water mark)

truncate table t
  drop all storage;

exec show_size;

Total Blocks:    0 (blocks in the segment)
Total Bytes:     0 (segment size in bytes)
Unused Blocks:   0 (empty blocks)
Unused Bytes:    0 (size of empty space in bytes)
Last Used Block: 0 (high water mark)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the detail answer @Chris

Answer (score 2):

If you're on 11g R2 or above, see whether `DROP ALL STORAGE` does what you want. Have a look at the following example:

```
SQL> create table test_truncate as select level id, sysdate + level datum
  2  from dual connect by level <= 100000;

Table created.

SQL> select segment_name,segment_type,bytes/1024/1024 MB
  2  from dba_segments
  3  where segment_type='TABLE' and segment_name='TEST_TRUNCATE';

SEGMENT_NAME         SEGMENT_TYPE               MB
-------------------- ------------------ ----------
TEST_TRUNCATE        TABLE                       3

SQL> truncate table test_truncate;

Table truncated.

SQL> select segment_name,segment_type,bytes/1024/1024 MB
  2  from dba_segments
  3  where segment_type='TABLE' and segment_name='TEST_TRUNCATE';

SEGMENT_NAME         SEGMENT_TYPE               MB
-------------------- ------------------ ----------
TEST_TRUNCATE        TABLE                   ,0625

SQL> truncate table test_truncate DROP ALL STORAGE;

Table truncated.

SQL> select segment_name,segment_type,bytes/1024/1024 MB
  2  from dba_segments
  3  where segment_type='TABLE' and segment_name='TEST_TRUNCATE';

no rows selected

SQL>
```

Comment: understood that drop storage will gain the storage after truncate table. I wanted to understand what will happen to table size if we delete data from table or truncate the table. I tried with you example @Littlefoot, and it seems when we delete all record from table the table size remain as it is, its only recovers when we truncate it. Is my understanding correct.

Comment: Note, when you run this statements on Oracle 11.1 (or prior) then even an empty table has `MINEXTENTS` extents with `INITIAL` size each. You can create table with clause `SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE` to get the same behavior also on current release. Oracle parameter `deferred_segment_creation` can also set it globally.

Answer (score 1):

I wonder you are not including the table structure to count in size. That size what is showed is the table's structure size.

```
 Tables whole size= Tables structure 
 (Table name and fields (0.0625 mb)) + 
 (records/the 
  data (remaining size in mb)) as per the 
above data u showed
```

To verify alter the table and delete one column/field

```
  ALTER TABLE SALES_HISTORY DROP 
  Sales;

 select  
 segment_name,segment_type,
bytes/1024/1024 MB
from dba_segments
where segment_type='TABLE' and 
segment_name='SALES_HISTORY';
```